# I am checking the internet connection at the start of my app and if not connected then it should show a alert message

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, oncreate, activity-lifecycle

```
if(haveNetworkConnection()==false)
    {
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 finish();

               }
            });

            alertDialog.show();

    }
```

I am checking the internet connection at the start of my app and if not connected then it should show a alert message, and on pressing ok should exit the app.This code does not work.

Comment: Post haveNetworkConnection code

Comment: `This code does not work.` is not very helpful description you know.

Comment: @Raghunandan : The haveNetworkConnection() code is working alright.

Comment: @poss : The application does start for around 5 seconds without displaying the MainActivity (It shows blank activity)and then it abruptly terminates ,saying - unfortunately, App has stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Really you shouldnt close your app just because you dont have a connection. Mobile connections can sometimes be erratic and this should be handled. But if you have to.

To check if you have an active connection you first have to make sure you have the right permissions set in your manifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

then you can use a method like this to check your connection

```
private Boolean haveNetworkConnection(){
     ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

     NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
             activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

     return isConnected;
}
```

finally to make sure you exit the app and not just close the activity call `System.exit(0);` instead of `finish()`

```
if(!haveNetworkConnection())
{
     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             System.exit(0);
           }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I am writing a app which fetches data at the start of my app from the internet(JSON parsing) and i put that data on my MainActivity, so if i write a code that still keeps my app running despite no network connection, then that would'nt make any sense , hence i chose to terminate my app when there is no network connection at the beginning of my app.Thanks for trying but this code dont seem to work. I have written this code in onCreate() - please correct me if i am doing anything wrong as i am a newbie to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any code for haveNetworkConnection() try replacing with this

```
public boolean haveNetworkConnection{

ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;

}
```

Comment: My haveNetworkConnection() method works fine. Thanks for the help anyway :)